# What is the technique to integrate $ \int_{0}^{3} x\ln(x) dx ?$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

What is the technique to integrate $$ \int_{0}^{3} x\ln(x) dx  ?$$
Why did one textbook evaluate this integral using the integration technique for improper integrals with a discontinuity on its integrand? Isn't it that we can only use that said technique if the integrand has an infinite discontinuity at some number on the interval of integration and if $$ \lim_{x\to 0+} \vert x\ln(x) \rvert = +\infty ?$$
But our integrand has no infinity discontinuity, but a removable disconituity at $x=0$. Also, $ \lim_{x\to 0+} \vert \ln(x) \rvert \neq +\infty $

I am thinking of redefining the integrand first before integrating. But is this even possible?

Comment: All your limits should be $x\to 0^+$ since they involve $\ln x.$

Comment: Since $z \; ln(z)$ is holomorphic within an open set that contains the contour $[r - \epsilon, r + \epsilon] \; \bigcup \; \{ \epsilon e^{i \theta} + r \} $ for $r - \epsilon > 0$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, then you can use Cauchy's Integral Theorem and a homotopy to the contour that approches including $[0,3]$ to solve for an answer.

Comment: @OliverDiaz So I can still use the integration technique for improper integrals?

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Thank you! But is that the simplest technique?

Comment: @PhillipHamilton: Introducing complex analysis and homotopy  is absolutely utter nonsense!  You will confuse the OP when the solution requires only basic Calculus.

Comment: @oliverdiaz oh yes you're right.  Sorry OP missed the calculus tag.  Thought I'd set my feed to complex analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

As outlined in my comments

1. Integration by parts gives
   $$
   \int x\log(x)\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\Big(\int \log(x)\,dx^2\Big)=\frac12\Big(x^2\log(x)-\int x\,dx\Big)=\frac{1}{2}x^2\log(x)-\frac{1}{4}x^2 +C
   $$
2. The main issue you seemed to have is the value of $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}x\log(x)$. This limit exists and is $0$. To convince yourself of this, you may use L'Hospital rule:
   $$
   x\log(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{1/x}\sim\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=-x\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0+}0
   $$
   There are other ways to do this but that will do.
3. Putting things together, you have that the integral you are interested to evaluate is
   $$\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}\Big(\frac{1}{2}x^2\log(x)-\frac{1}{4}x^2\Big)\Big|^3_a=\frac{9}{2}\log 3-\frac{9}{4}-\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}\Big(\frac{1}{2}a^2\log(a)-\frac{a^2}{4}\Big)=?
   $$

I hope this helps you and you can estimate the last bit.